# Are cell phone and tablet cameras adequate to read 1D barcodes?

Tags: android, hardware, barcode, zxing

I'm using ZXing barcode scanner with my project and I am having issues with 1D barcodes. The average success of scanning the barcode is 6 out of 10. 6 times the code comes right, but 4 of them the numbers come all shuffled. So the question is, should I try to change the requirements and use QR Code (the camera never fails reading QR Code), or is there a workaround to this, such as some kind of validation so I can emit a error message?

Thanks in advance.

edit: Code 128 was the one I should have used since the beginning. The device has no problem with reading the code. Thank you for all the information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you chose a 1D format without a checksum -- like Code 39? It's pretty prone to misreads as a result. Use Code 128, or better still, a QR code.

Comment: While I agree that QR codes have a lot of advantages, I'm glad you suggested the Code 128 option.  From the initial question, it appears that he has a requirement for a "Barcode" and may not be open to QR coding.

Comment: You got that right, I'm using Code 39. I'll try Code 128 tomorrow.

@dan_linder The 1D code is the one in the requirements. Also, all I need is one code, doesn't really matter the length, it only needs to be unique. So I guess QR is not really what I'm looking for here, but I'll try to use in last case.

Answer (score 2):

The cameras are more than adequate. 1D barcodes are just hard to read.  I'd switch to QR codes if possible.  Here are some links you might find helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4648938/517561
http://www.scandit.com/2011/10/13/barcode-101-upc-ean-code128-vs-qr-datamatrix/

Comment: From what I read, I should probably use 1D. The problem is if the numbers come shuffled. Also, I need to see if QR Codes can fit into Watchbands.